# How to prompt message if field is empty, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this field for search and image field , in search form I have a button submit it works but when I clicked it and there's no input in the input field it shows error and in the image field if I don't add an image it shows error... Do I solve this through a prompt message? to let the users know that that field is empty. Here's my code for search

building.blade.php

```
 {!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}
        <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
         <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
           </button>
          </span>
            </div>    
             {!! Form::close()!!}
```

OfficeController.php

```
 public function index()
{ 
  $search = \Request::get('search');
    $offices = Office::where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get(); 
    return view('search',compact('offices','search'));                  
  }
```

createbuilding.blade.php

```
{!! Form::label('Building Photo') !!}
  {!! Form::file('buildingpics',array('onchange'=>'previewFile()')) !!}
  <img src="../assets/imageholder.png" id="previewImg" style="height:300px; width:300px;" alt="">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Building 
        </button>

  <!--  {!! Form::submit('Create Building',
      array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!} -->

      <a href="{{route('index')}}" class="btn btn-default btn-md"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Back</a>
</div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}


<script type="text/javascript">

function previewFile() {
var preview = document.querySelector('#previewImg');
var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
var reader  = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
  preview.src = reader.result;
}, false);

if (file) {
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
}
</script>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

You can validate it by using laravel validate method in your controller just put the validate code in your controller like

```
$this->validate($request, [
                        'field_name1' => 'required',
                        'field_name2' => 'required',                        
                    ]);
```

and in your view just popup the error message so if the user is not fill the field or the field is empty then it show the error message on the submit of the request so user can easily understand what is required.

```
   @if ($errors->any())
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                     <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
             </ul>
             </div>
             @endif
        <!--error ends-->
```

Hope this code will help you to shortout the what you want.

Comment: `public function index()
    {
        
        $search = \Request::get('search');
        $offices = Office::where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get(); 

        return view('search',compact('offices','search')); 

        $this->validate($request, [
                        'search' => 'required',
                                         
                    ]);            

       
      }`

Comment: is it right? @Anil Kumar Sahu 

where do I put the 2nd one?

Comment: second one you have to put inside the view file before or after the form

Comment: kindly pass the Request in your index like public function index(Request $request) {    }

Comment: I dont understand, sorry Im kinda new to laravel @Anil Kumar Sahu

Comment: modify your controller code like public function index(Request $request) { 
$search = $request::get('search'); 
$offices = Office::where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get(); 
return view('search',compact('offices','search'));
 $this->validate($request, [ 'search' => 'required', ]);

 }

Comment: I dont know why its not working, but I added the required in my input field and it shows message, but how to show something like "not found" message in search @Anil Kumar Sahu

Answer (score 0):

You can either go with HTML5 required attribute like so

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." required>
```

or

You can user Laravel's Form Request Validation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: simply add required attribute to your input field
<input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." required>

Comment: yah it shows message but what if the user searches wrong and it will show  not found how do I do that?

Comment: How to show search not found message if i get no result from search @Samjunior